# Re-render React component back to original state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this component that returns a bunch of li's on a axios get request, users input text and the search is updated..I want React to re-render the component when the searchInput is null, basically back to its original state.

```
  class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      searchResults: [], // API Call returns an array of results
      searchInput: '', // Search Term for API Call
            searchImage: [] //base_url, a file_size and a file_path.
    }
  }


performSearch = () => { // Requesting data from API
    axios.get(`${URL}api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&query=${this.state.searchInput}${PARAMS}`)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data.results);
            this.setState({ searchResults: res.data.results});
        });
}
```

This function below is what triggers the rendering

```
   handleInputChange = () => {
        this.setState({
            searchInput: this.search.value // User input
        }, () => {
            if (this.state.searchInput && this.state.searchInput.length >1 ) {
                if (this.state.searchInput.length % 2 === 0) { // Request data on user input
                    this.performSearch();
                } else if (this.state.searchInput && this.state.searchInput.length === 0 ) {
                    return ({ searchResults: null}) 
                }
            }
        });
    }




import React from 'react'

const Suggestions = (props) => {
  const options = props.searchResults.map(r => (
    <li
      key={r.id} >
      <img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/${r.poster_path}`} alt={r.title} />
      <a href='#t' className='rating'><i className='fas fa-star fa-fw' />{r.vote_average}</a>
    </li>
  ))
  return <ul className='search-results'>{options}</ul>
}

export default Suggestions
```

Issue at the moment is that is that if I search something, eg 'game of thrones' it renders the li's, however if I clear it back to an empty string, I still have left over li's...I dont't wanna see anything if the searchInput is null

Edit: performSearch is fires again while clearing searchInput and returns the last two characters which leaves me with left over li's

Comment: set the searchResults to an empty array when the value of searchInput is empty. Also, the length check is not required as empty string is false

Comment: Still doesnt work, I've tried the solution below too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't handled the conditions correct in the `handleInputChange` method. If the outer condition fails, the inner won't ever execute

```
 handleInputChange = () => {
    this.setState({
        searchInput: this.search.value // User input
    }, () => {
        if (this.state.searchInput && this.state.searchInput.length >1 ) {
            if (this.state.searchInput.length % 2 === 0) { // Request data on user input
                this.performSearch();
            }
        } else {
             this.now = Date.now();
             this.setState({ searchResults: []}) 
        }
    });
}
```

Also the issue here could possible be the race condition with the API calls. It might so happen that when you clear the input although you setState to null or empty, the API then responds which sets the state again. The best way to handle is to accept only response that corresponds to the last request made

```
performSearch = () => { // Requesting data from API
    let now = (this.now = Date.now());
    axios.get(`${URL}api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&query=${this.state.searchInput}${PARAMS}`)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data.results);
            // Accepting response if this request was the last request made
            if (now === this.now) {
               this.setState({ searchResults: res.data.results});
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Still have left over li's

Comment: How are you rendering the list elements

Comment: <div className='search-results-div'>
          <Suggestions searchResults={this.state.searchResults} />
  </div>

Comment: Is suggestion your custom component or some library. Probably instead of null, you need to pass it an empty array

Comment: It's a custom component, i've updated original post, and I've tried the empty array too

Comment: From what it seems from your post, the li's should go away once the data is cleared, maybe there is some other issue. A reproducible demo would be great to debug

Comment: No clue how to do that sorry :( but it seems the last that the left over li's are from whatever the last two characters are in seachInput - which is from this.performSearch

Comment: ok I kind of get what the issue could be. Updating the answer in a while

Comment: Hey man, I really appreciate the time you took to help with this, your edited solution fixed the problem I was having. Thanks man!

Comment: Glad to have helped. Your last comment really helped in figuring out the issue